# Entity Framework add assocations to many to many by key only

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

Suppose you have one of the simplest text book models:

```
Product {
    Categories
}
```

Where a product can be associated to 0 to many categories.

Suppose category looks similar to

```
Category {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name {get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to associate my product to (existing) categories with ids 1, 2, and 3. Is there anyway to create this association  without loading categories 1, 2, and 3 into memory?

I know this would be possible with a single Category where my Product model had Category and CategoryId on it. Is there a similar convention for bonding multiple items?

To reiterate, my purpose is to **avoid querying categories**. I already have the identifiers. With direct sql I could easily establish these relationships by key only (in fact the association table is literally just the keys). I want to know if there's an "*entity framework way*" of doing this or whether direct sql is the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create category instances with just the id and attach them to the context. Then you could add to the product, without having to pull the categories from the database.

For example:-

```
var category = new Category { Id = 1 };
db.Categories.Attach(category);
product.Categories.Add(category);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I was guessing it would involve attach, thanks for the input. I couldn't find anything specific with my initial googles